# How do I get core to detect when a module adds a new service?

Tags: 8, services, updating

I created a module that we are using internally for at least two projects. I pull it in via Composer and it ends up in modules/contrib. The first install went great, but now I have added a few services so that I can use the Drupal DI container and when I update the module on the Drupal end (using Composer update) it says that the service doesn't exist.

I have tried running `drush cr` and `drush updb` to no avail. The services are defined in a `mymodule.services.yml` file and the original services were detected and used upon install. I have since added two more services and it is those two it does not seem to detect until I uninstall and reinstall the module.

Running `drush cr` does not seem to fix the problem, nor does `drush updb`.

**Error in the logs is:**

`Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: "You have requested a non-existent service "endpoint.placeable.search"." at MY_SITE_PATH/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php line 157`

Aside from uninstalling and reinstalling the module, what else we can do? Surely there has got to be a way to rescan a module directory for services changes.

To be clear, this is in Drupal 8.

Comment: maybe you have a typo in the path in your services.yml file? because in theory, you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: I should clarify that it detected the existing services on install just fine. I wasn't able to get it to recognize the two new services until I uninstalled and reinstalled the module.

Comment: When adding new services, just rebuilding the cache should do the trick. (At least it does for me).

Comment: I will try again on a different machine.

Comment: Nope, does not work.

Comment: You can add a new service by rebuilding the cache. The problem here is an unsolved dependency. You can try to do it in two steps, first add the service in the error message, then the one that depends on it.

Comment: @4k4: Aside from adding it to the `mymodule.services.yml` file, which is where it was added, how exactly do I add the new service? Because clearly rebuilding the cache is not the solution

Comment: @pthurmond, this is the right way. Read the error message. You have a problem that the service `endpoint.placeable.search` can't be injected into another service. So add first only this service and clear the cache. Check for errors. If all is OK, try the next service.